# How can i get the names of the Bluetooth devices that are in range?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi i want to develop an app and i want to save in an array the list of the devices in range from my android phone. I want to use the names of these devices so is it possible to get them somehow? Also can i programmatically change the bluetooth name?

Answer (score 1):

You should stick to this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html) and this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html).